# Need to unpivot columns with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a table below where the formula for each brand's quantity is equal to the sum of each sub-brands quantity. For example: JPGL=JPGL FF+JPGL Switch & LS=LS Berry+ LS Lemon & Star=Star FF+ Star Next

| Customer | JPGL FF | JPGL Switch | JPGL | LS Berry | LS Lemon | LS | Star Next | Star FF | Star |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 200 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 4 |

I need to transform it into a flattened table by SQL unpivot query Like below: Please assist.

| Customer | Brand | Sub-Brand | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | JPGL | JPGL FF | 1 |
| 100 | JPGL | JPGL Switch | 1 |
| 100 | LS | LS Berry | 3 |
| 100 | LS | LS Lemon | 4 |
| 100 | Star | Star FF | 2 |
| 100 | Star | Star Next | 3 |
| 200 | JPGL | JPGL FF | 2 |
| 200 | JPGL | JPGL Switch | 2 |
| 200 | LS | LS Berry | 1 |
| 200 | LS | LS Lemon | 1 |
| 200 | Star | Star FF | 3 |
| 200 | Star | Star Next | 1 |

Comment: What have you [tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)? Please share your current query that you are having trouble with.

Comment: SELECT     [Customer]
    ,up.Brand
   ,up.Qty
    
   FROM [MyTable] 
 
   UNPIVOT 
  (
    Qty FOR Brand IN ( [JPGL,[LS],[Star]
     
  ) AS up
 
GO

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SubBrand (example: JPGL FF, LS Berry...) for the unpivoted columns.
2. For Brand column, use `SUBSTRING` to get the word before space.

```
SELECT [Customer], 
  SUBSTRING(up.Brand, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', up.Brand, 0)) [Brand],
  up.Brand AS [SubBrand],
  up.Qty 
FROM [MyTable]
UNPIVOT ( 
  Qty FOR Brand IN ([JPGL FF], [JPGL SWITCH], [LS Berry], [LS Lemon], [Star FF], [Star Next]) 
)
AS up
```

[Sample DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69c913ab7a56b65a5398e2c5428bb3b4)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However Brand is not always the substring from Sub-Brand in my actual database. So what will be the approach then?

Comment: For such case, based on the provided table, how to determine which is a sub-brand or brand? Or do you have another table that determines the sub-brand under which brand? If you have another table as mentioned, this will be easy to do by joining the unpivoted table. And do share the table to the question as well.